# Plot with and without `Table` produce different results

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

Suppose a function

```
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda))
```

where

```
n = 1; beta = 0.6; i = 0.05; W = 60;
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
b[e_] := b /. Solve[a W (1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda - 1)- b \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)] - 1\)]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\) == b + a W, b][[1]];
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
```

I would like to plot `e` that maximizes `v` with respect to `w` for a specific value of `a`, for example, `a = 0.9`. I tried two different ways, i.e. with and without `Table`, expecting to get the same result but I didn't.

The first one is

```
a = 0.9;
brf[w_] := ArgMax[{v, e > 0, e < 1, Uem > Uun}, e];
Plot[brf[w], {w, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 1}}]
```

which yielded

[image]

The second one uses `Table`:

```
brf[a_, w_] := ArgMax[{v, e >= 0, e <= 1, Uem > Uun}, e];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Simplify@brf[a, w], {a, {0.9}}], {w, 0, 12}]
```

which yielded

[image]

Why do they produce different results? Aren't they supposed to produce the same result?

Comment: Am the only one getting errors when trying the code?

Comment: @bmf No you aren't , Mathematica v12.2 doesn't evaluate the code !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, thanks, any solution?

Comment: @ppp How did you produce the two solutions?